# Removing a dictionary from a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary has two key-value pairs. Something like

```
l1 = [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},
      {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},
      ...
     ]
```

Now what I want is to remove a dictionary from this list just be checking first `key` and its `value`. I can check whether a whole dictionary is present in the list and then remove it. But I just want to check whether a dictionary with a particular `first key` is present or not in the list. Such a dictionary will be unique. And I want to remove that dictionary from this list subsequently. How do I do that?

Edit: While removing, I have only one key-value pair. So I want to remove the dictionary using one pair only. If I had both the pairs then I could have done

```
l1.remove({'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'})
```

But this is not the case as I do not have another pair. That's why I said that dictionary is unique.

Comment: Are you wanting to do something different than looping through each dictionary, checking it, and removing it if necessary?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid looping through whole list and check `first key` of every dictionary

Comment: dictionary does not have any sequence. So first key can be any value

Comment: I'm assuming when Naman says 'first_key' it is a particular field he is checking.

Comment: There is no first key in a dict, dicts are unordered

Comment: @CollinGreen sorry for late reply but yes, I want to remove the dictionary from that list if a particular key-value pair is present(without creating a new list)

Answer (score 8):

Given,

```
ds = [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'},
      {'key1', 'value3', 'key2', 'value4'},
      ...]
```

You can remove a dictionary with a unique key-value using a list comprehension:

```
ds = [d for d in ds if d['key1'] != 'value1']
```

But then you are traversing the entire list, creating a new list without that dictionary, and not capturing the dictionary. You can also do this manually:

```
for i, d in enumerate(ds):
    if d['key1'] == 'value1':
        d1 = ds.pop(i)
        break
```

In which case you only traverse what you must, don't create a new list, and capture the dictionary. However, if you really care about performance (and don't care about order), I would suggest grouping the dictionaries by their unique key value to begin with:

```
ds = {'value1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'},
      'value3': {'key1', 'value3', 'key2', 'value4'},
      ...}
```

Because `ds['value1']` is O(1) (immediate), whereas any traversal is O(n) (has to go over the entire list in the worst case).

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your lists `list`!

Use list comprehension.

**key-value pair**

To remove list elements when a particular key-value pair is present:

```
l1 = [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},
        {'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]
l2 = [element for element in l1 if element.get('key1', '') != 'value1']
```

(Notice the `get` method with a default return value).

**key present**

To remove list elements when a particular key is present:

```
l2 = [element for element in l1 if 'key1' in element]
```

**Remarks**

- standard dictionaries are unordered, so there is no such thing as a "first" key.

Comment: I made two answers since the question has been edited while I was typing.

Comment: Since Naman said the target dict is unique, if the list is very long you might get better performance if you instead manually loop through it, remove the target dict when found, then break instead of building a new list out of every entry except the one.

Comment: I have made an edit to make it more clear. Please see it. Due to constraints, I cant make another list

Comment: Fine, in that case @Dan Gittik 's answer might be best.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned it, you could also loop over the list and use the 'del' keyword on dict you are targeting.

```
for i, j in enumerate(l1):
  if j['key1'] whatever logic:
      del l1[i]
```